# CDROM not showing up on Lenovo G50

Tags: debian, drivers, data-cd

I'm running Jessie/sid as my base.

When I type lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

When I type lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6513 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can't figure out which device is the cdrom drive.

cat /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info is empty of values.

There isn't even an eject button.

uname reads:

```
Linux DarthVader 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which kernel version?

Comment: Is it disabled in UEFI/ROM setup?

Comment: It's not disabled in UEFI ROM. Secure boot is also disabled. The emulation is set to AHCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard, This version of the laptop I purchased does not come with a CDROM.

Comment: What a way to blow 50RP.

Comment: How did you not notice this when you were running `lspci` and everything else?

Comment: @ekaj My dvd drive does not show up in `lspci` or `lsusb`. I own a Thinkpad T420. With a drive. My question would be: How did you not see there IS NO DRIVE?

Comment: They put a cover on the slot and make it look like it does.  But there is no eject button. So you start thinking that its a software driven eject like macs. But no. It does not have a button on the slot because it doe snot have a drive.